# How do I combine an Output of two for loops into a "table" format?

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans

I used two for loops to convert miles to km and km to miles respectively for selected values. However the issue I am facing is that the output for the first for loop is not side by side with the output of the second table. Appreciate some help on this!

```
public static double miletoKilometer(double mile) {
 double conversion = mile * 1.609;
 return conversion;
}

public static double kilometerToMile(double km) {
 double conversion2 = km / 1.609;
 return conversion2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 int mileInput = 0;
 double kmOutput = 0;
 int kmInput = 0;
 double mileOutput = 0;
 int displayRow1 = 0;
 int displayRow2 = 0;
 System.out.print("Miles\tKilometres\tKilometres\tMiles \n");

 for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 10) {
   mileInput = i;
   System.out.printf("\n" + i);
   kmOutput = miletoKilometer(mileInput);
   System.out.printf("\t %.3f\n", kmOutput);
  }
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < 66; j++) {
  if (j == 20 || j == 25 || j == 60 || j == 65) {
   kmInput = j;
   System.out.printf("\n\t\t         " + j);
   mileOutput = kilometerToMile(kmInput);
   System.out.printf("\t\t%.3f", mileOutput);
  }

 }
}
```

Current Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCdyZ.png)

Comment: Since your output is of dimension 4x4, you could e.g. create an array `Float[4][4]`, populate it in the loops and do all printing afterwards using the array.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your loop to match the code below should put everything in the right order. Not the most elegant solution but it gets the job done.

```
        int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 10) {
           mileInput = i;
           System.out.printf("\n" + i);
           kmOutput = miletoKilometer(mileInput);
           System.out.printf("\t %.3f", kmOutput);
           for (; j < 66; j++) {
               if (j == 20 || j == 25 || j == 60 || j == 65) {
                 kmInput = j;
                 System.out.printf("\t\t         " + j);
                 mileOutput = kilometerToMile(kmInput);
                 System.out.printf("\t\t%.3f\n", mileOutput);
                 j++;
                 break;
              }
          }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help brother, appreciate it :)!

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer please if it solved your problem.